# qBittorrent: how to add a torrent using it's hash?

Tags: bittorrent

I did try to Use "add torrent link" pasting

`magnet:?xt=urn:btih:INFOHASH` (where the INFOHASH is the hash number)

But the hash appear like 00000000000000000

[image]

Any idea how to add a torrent from the hash ?

Comment: Try `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:00000000000000000` where 00000000000000000 is the hash. Or did you try this and it put it as zeros?

Comment: I tried that one: magnet:?xt=urn:btih:f113c4f0eb3e8dde4edf42a2e1f3a952

Comment: Have you tried adding a magnet link and just adding the hash? if not you could use this [link](http://romanr.info/magnet.html) to convert the Hash to a magnet link.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin thanks! I just tried but with the same result

Comment: Added qbittorrent for you. And are you sure you have the correct hash?

Comment: Does this happen for any torrent? If its a legitimate download - like a linux livecd, the link might help.

Comment: I know why it did not work: the torrent page and hash was fake. I tried several others coming from other torrent db and they worked. It was confusing because the page was an exact copy of the kat page, showing seeds, torrent quality, etc. but it was a fake. So I least I know that magnet:?xt=urn:btih:HASH work, and  the 0000000 shows when the torrent doesn't exist. I apologize, i should have check the website before making my tests.

Comment: The hexencoded infohash in the example (magnet:?xt=urn:btih:f113c4f0eb3e8dde4edf42a2e1f3a952) is only 32 characters long. It should be 40. That's why it didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

you must need trackers for a torrent to be downloaded in magnet link here is an api which gives you current seeders and leechers include with the magnet link by just using the torrent infohash

https://hash2seed.torrentsnows.com/

try this hash to magnet generating api
hope this helps